# iframe won't accept variables from URL

Tags: php, url, iframe

I have two files, stages_detail.php is embedded within stages_scroll.php as an iframe. I am trying to pass variables from the URL details in stages_detail.php and to stages_scroll.php simultaneously, when a user clicks on the page links in stages_detail.php

The url and the variables are passed via code such as the following:

```
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $Stages_Detail . '?pn=' . $add1 . '&jrny='.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$add1.'&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$Table_Id.'">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
```

and the embedded file contained within stages_scroll.php is referenced as follows

```
 <?php

$src = 'stages_detail.php?pn=' . $sub1 . '&jrny='.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$sub1. '&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$Table_Id;

echo '<iframe align="center" width=1900 height= 300 src="'.$src.'" frameborder="yes" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe>';
?>
```

Comment: What is `$sub1` etc? Defined like `$sub1 = $_POST['something'];`? or does `stages_detail.php` not accept GETs? If the latter than we need to see that code..

Comment: And how it is defined?

Comment: None of that relates to `post` or `get` so that can't be related. Is `$pn` defined by `post`? You can use `$_REQUEST` in place of `post`/`get` and it will check `post`, `get`, and `cookie`.

Comment: Originally when users come to the page it is via post, and in further selections via GET

    ``if (isset($_POST['pn'])) {
    $pn = $_POST['pn'];
}

if (isset($_GET['pn'])) {
    $pn = $_GET['pn'];
}``

Comment: Apologies @chris85, stages_detail.php is embedded in stages_scroll.php and the variables cannot be passed via the URL contained in the pagination code to scroll.php and stages_detail.php simultaneously. The pagination links are on the stages_detail.php page and the code for the centre pages reads as follows:


   ``$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $Stages_Detail . '?pn=' . $add1 . '&jrny='.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$add1.'&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$Table_Id.'">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';``

Comment: Use `$_REQUEST` instead of checking `POST` and `GET`. Please update your question with the additional code, execution path, and the two pages relations.